# Why this statement invalid: `VALUES ( CURRENT PACKAGESET )`?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-10.5

I'm on db2 luw 10.5.

db2 special registers can be set with:

```
SET CURRENT ...
```

and retrieved with:

```
VALUES CURRENT ...
```

with the exception of `CURRENT PACKAGESET`. For some reason the following statement fails:

```
VALUES CURRENT PACKAGESET
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "PACKAGESET" was found following "VALUES CURRENT
".  Expected tokens may include:  "END-OF-STATEMENT".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Why so?

Comment: What version of DB2 are you using?

Comment: @Lennart db2 luw 10.5

Answer (score 2):

I dont think CURRENT PACKAGESET is a special register in LUW 10.5. The special registers can be found at:

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008404.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-2-5

SET CURRENT PACKAGESET is a statement that can only be embedded in an application program:

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001005.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-219&lang=en